# Cross compile C/Cpp application for target ARM arch support ubuntu18.04 32-bit, on host machine i.e. ubuntu 18.04 64-bit machine using cross compiler

Tags: compiling, 64-bit, gcc, c++, arm

Trying to achieve the below task

> Cross compile C/Cpp application for target ARM architechture supports ubuntu 18.04 32-bit on a host machine i.e. ubuntu 18.04 64-bit machine using cross compiler.

followed steps below but nothing is working out and getting the Error given below..

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-7-multilib

/home/user/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.04_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc main.c -m32 -o main
```

Error

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: command not found
```

Help is highly appreciated..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having toolchain extracted into home directory without adjusting PATH-variable  will not work.

You need to install different package which provides [`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` executable](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc) by

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

and then use `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` command.